# JQuery blur event

Tags: jquery

JQuery blur event on a row triggers when ever an element in a row looses its focus. For the following example I have a sample table and there are two input fields in each row; if we try to execute this code and user leave focus from one input control to another in same row i get the blur event triggered for that row. Thoughts?

```
<table id="sample" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>            
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>            
        <td>2.2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>            
        <td>3.2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4.1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>            
        <td>4.2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" " /></td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sample').delegate('tr', 'blur', function (event) {
            alert('Row Blurred');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `live` and `delegate` methods do not support the `blur` event, since it doesn't bubble.
Instead, handle `focusout`, which they do support

Comment: Yes you are right as per the documentation; but if you try this sample out with both blur and focusout events for IE9 you will get the same behaviour.

Comment: i am trying to have focusout event only when a row in a table lost a focus.

Comment: @Matloob: Rows don't have focus.  You need to bind to the `<input>` elements.

Comment: @SLaks try this code out, first remove input elements. Then click on the first row and then click on the document or to the second row you will get focus out event fired for each row.

Comment: @Matloob: You're catching the events after they bubble up from the `<input>`s.  The rows themselves do not have focus.

Comment: jQuery maps blur to the focusout event in its event delegation methods, .live() and .delegate(). http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Heads up `backbone.marionette` users: you must use `focusout` rather than `blur` in your events hash for itemviews with `tagname: 'tr'`. This answer saved me!